# Mathematical symbol: An operator as a map from a vector space into itself

Tags: math-operators

My professor had a nice notation that he used for operators on vector spaces that I thought was clear. It wasn't something like `$L: \mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{V}$` but rather a hooked arrow that reinforced that concept that `$L$` is a map from `$\mathcal{V}$` into itself.

Here is an example of exactly what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you meaning `\hookrightarrow`?

Comment: Hi. No I am looking more for something along the lines of what is picture here: http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/e2/dd/e2dd0348ee15d87050c4864e2986f93a.png but with the upper line being equal length to the lower line.

Comment: `\hookleftarrow`?

Answer (score 1):

Load `\usepackage{mathabx}` and then

```
$L: \mathcal{V} \righttoleftarrow$
```

[image]

For more symbols, [check here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: That is very nice. Thank you. Do you know if there is one with less curvature?

Comment: @Johnver, I don't think so. Please, check the link I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility formed by superimposing a `\supset` symbol with a small arrowhead using `\lefteqn`. I used `\blacktriangleleft` scaled by 50% for the arrowhead.

[image]

Then I scaled the whole symbol to 85% (you could adjust this) and wrapped it in a `\mathbin` for spacing. Note also the use of `\colon` instead of `:` for proper spacing of functions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} % for \blacktriangleleft symbol
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \scalebox command

\newcommand{\toitself}{\mathbin{\scalebox{.85}{%
    \lefteqn{\scalebox{.5}{$\blacktriangleleft$}}\raisebox{.34ex}{$\supset$}}}}

\begin{document}

$L\colon\mathcal{V}\toitself\mathcal{V}$

\end{document}
```